# how to setup AWS S3 to stream HLS video to my android app securely?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am a beginner at amazon web services(AWS). actually, I have an app that streams HLS videos through Exoplayer (Url of videos are retrieved by firebase database).
Now the only thing is left to serve videos from the best cloud storage so I chose AWS. But I have no idea how I can stream the videos securely and cost-effectively by AWS correctly.

I have tested some streams through AWS for only a day. and I was notified that I have used 85% of the AWS Free Tier limit.

Actually, I enabled full public access to my S3 bucket and converted the mp4 file to an Apple Hls streaming file by AWS-MediaConvert, but my manifest file was not loading. so I changed the manifest file

**from this**

```
 #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=180480,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=165470,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=406x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000
400k.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=180480,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=165470,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=406x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000
600k.m3u8
```

**to this**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=180480,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=165470,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=406x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000
https://PATH_OF_MY_S3.amazonaws.com/Ball+Launcher+Using+Sodium+Metal+%23Shortstest/400k.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=180480,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=165470,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=406x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000
https://PATH_OF_MY_S3.amazonaws.com/Ball+Launcher+Using+Sodium+Metal+%23Shortstest/600k.m3u8
```

Then it was working by streaming from its direct link and from CloudFront also. But I don't think that it is the correct way for security and my budget.
Does someOne have a solution that how can I do this in the correct way??

Comment: Maybe this blog post will give you some hints: https://hlsbook.net/how-to-serve-hls-video-from-an-s3-bucket/

Comment: Hii @Chris, how can I give permission to only my app to access those streams? I have to use my app's package name or other certificates? thanks for your response.

Comment: @AbhayKumarTiwari Based of your use case, perhaps you might want to consider this approach?
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/secure-content-using-cloudfront-functions/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGjdTKQnG4g&ab_channel=TechopediaTherapy

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudfront (CDN) to stream your videos securely. The HLS endpoint with cloudfront will look something like this

{cdn_domain_name}/{path_to_your_m3u8_file}/{file}.m3u8

This you can directly pass in your ExoPlayer src.